# Remove Blue border in IE 10 Compatibility View

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, hyperlink, internet-explorer-10

How can I remove or just don't display the border links in every anchor with image? By the way, browser settings is in compatibility mode. Answers from other question doesn't suffice to solve my problem. I guess because it only applies with lower version of IE.

**EDIT:**

I'm currently creating a Custom share buttons where my client requires me.

```
<div>
    <a onClick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=#shareLink#&text=#shareTitle#&tw_p=tweetbutton&url=#shareLink#','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">
        <img height="20" src="/images/chicklets/Twitter_Tweet.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=#shareTitle#&amp;p[summary]=#shareDesc#&amp;p[url]=#shareLink#&amp;p[images][0]=images/Telos.jpg','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">
        <img height="20" src="/images/chicklets/FaceBook_Share.png">
    </a>
</div>

<div>
    <a onClick="window.open('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=#shareLink#&title=#shareTitle#&summary=#shareDesc#','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">
        <img height="20" src="/images/chicklets/LinkedIn_Share.png">
    </a>
</div>      

<div>
    <a onClick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=#shareLink#','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">
        <img height="20" src="/images/chicklets/Google_PlusOne.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
a {
    outline : none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a img {
    outline : none;
}
img {
    border : 0;
    border-style: none;
}
div {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Here's what it looks like with IE10:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to add `border="0"` or in CSS `border: none` to `<img>`? it applies to all versions of IE.

Comment: Yup, I already put those suggestion, yet none of those solved mine. :(

Comment: just adding it to `img` may not be enough, try `a img {border: none}` in your CSS. You may also have to emphasize it by adding `!important`

Comment: I already added these with my CSS `a {outline : none !important;} a img {outline : none !important;} img {border : 0 !important;}`. Nothing Change. Is there an issue with this?

Comment: can you show your image tag code ?

Comment: incorrect HTML . you mixed up HTML & CSS syntax: `<img height="20px" `. If I were you, I will inspect the CSS with Fiddler or something similar to find out who gives you the border

Comment: I already checked this and update my question. Thanks for looking for it

Comment: @ShivanRaptor `height` is a property of `img` independent from CSS

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I know. Just want to point out that height attribute should not have `px` as unit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about this, try to add something like this

```
<img src="blah" style="border-style:none;">
```

Comment: Vava voom! Works like a charm! Thanks @kyawagvin, anyway I'm bit curious why that thing occurred with IE10 :(

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this as part of my normal defaulting set up in my CSS:

```
img {border: none;}
```

This doesn't effect the other browsers negatively and is easy to over-ride at a later point if you place this near the top of you general css file e.g

```
img {border: none;}
img.some-class {border: 1px double blue}
```

Where the increased specificity will add an ugly border to your image just like IE loves doing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue with IE10. I've just set up a CSS rule for the a tag and set the text colour to white. This removes the blue line from around an anchor image.