# Image PNG on Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: html, css, web

because a png image that I put in the header of my website on all browsers display correctly on Internet Explorer and 10 displays a square around it? I'm going crazy trying to figure out why. Can anyone help me? The image has no background, is transparent. I attach a screenshot for you to understand the problem better.

[image]

The blue part is the logo (which I covered)

Answer (score 1):

`<a href="http://www.boutell.com/">
<img src="/boutellcomlogo.png" style="border-style: none"/>
</a>`

An even cleaner solution, if you never want the blue border, is to say so in a style sheet:

```
img
  {  
    border-style: none;
  }
```

And then reference that style sheet in the head element of your page:one

or

```
 img
  {
     border: 0 none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the blue border you can use the border attribute for the img element like so:

You need to set the Border to 0 or None:

There are two ways to delete the Border using CSS or Direct way

Direct implementation is

`<a href="#"><img src="image path"  alt="" border="none"></a>`

Using CSS :

`<style type="text/css">
a img {border:none;}
</style>`

HTML

`<a href="#"><img src="image path"  alt=""></a>`

Answer (score 0):

It's IE10 issue. Give it a style and remove the border.

```
<img src="/YourImage.png" style="border-style:none;">
```

[Same issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826859/remove-blue-border-in-ie-10-compatibility-view)

Answer (score 0):

People say that this is an issue of IE, but its actually not exactly an issue,
its just their browsers default CSS rule which in a lot of cases is overridden.
Basically if you are making a page that is compatible with a lot of browsers, specially if
IE is included in that case its wise to use [Reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), which reduces the browser inconsistencies and which allows you to specify your own rules from scratch.
I know you got your answer, but I would recommend this approach.